# FastAPI - Is it possible access another input parameter in a validator?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I am new to FastAPI and I am trying to get one input parameter (token) into the Provision Class and use it in a @validator. But I can not figure out how to get access to the token in the validator. Is it even possible?

```
from typing import Annotated 
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

app = FastAPI()

def decryptJWT(token):
    return {"app": "app1"}

def appAuth(token):
    sub = decryptJWT(token)
    if sub["app"] in ["app1", "app2"]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

class Provision(BaseModel):
    name: str
    app: str

    @validator("app")
    def app_must_be_valid(cls, app):
        apps = appAuth(token)
        if app not in apps:
            raise ValueError("Invalid app name")
        return app

@app.post("/provision")
async def provision(token, provision: Provision):
    return provision
```

I am getting the token via the Authorization header `token: Annotated[OAuth2PasswordBearer, Depends(verifyAuthScope('write')]`.

I want to verify that "provision.application" input matches one of the applications that are mapped to the user. The user (clientid) to applications ([]) mapping exists in a database. There is no way of getting this info solely based on claims in the token. The solution that I have in place right now, is to verify in the path operation function itself, and here I do obviously have access to both the token and the "provision.application" input that was provided. To keep the code clean, and keep the "errors" consistent (ValueError instead of HTTPException etc.) I would like to do the "input validation" early, before the path operation function code is executed.

Here´s an excerpt of the code used right now in the path operation function (cleaned up from error handling and logging):

```
def verify_application_mapping(provision, token):
    applications = clientid_mapped_to_application(token)
    for app in applications:
        if provision.application in app['name']:
            return True
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='Invalid Application: "{}". Valid Applications are: {}'.format(provision.application, [app['name'] for app in applications]))

    return False
```

Comment: Have you seen model validators? https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#model-validators They're meant for validation that require more than a single field.

Comment: Haven´t seen this before and I do have cases where this would be a nice solution actually!! So I am going to try it out! But for this issue, since my main concern is how to get access to the token in the model, I do not see how the model validators would help me here unfortunately!

Comment: In that case I'd place the responsibility in your service layer / dependency function, not the pydantic model itself

Answer (score 0):

Usually we treat `JWT` tokens in headers or/and cookies. But, based on this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130548/should-jwt-token-be-stored-in-a-cookie-header-or-body) we can see that there is not any `"strandard"` way of how we should treat them.

So, here is 3 examples of how you can resolve your issue:

```
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import Body, Depends, FastAPI, Header, Request, status
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator

app = FastAPI()

APPS = ["app1", "app2"]


class Provision(BaseModel):
    name: str
    app: str


class Payload(BaseModel):
    token: str


class ProvisionAnotherWay(Provision):
    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def validate_token(cls, payload: dict[str, str]) -> dict[str, str]:
        out = check_token(payload["token"])
        return {"name": f"Name for token {payload['token']}", "app": out["app"]}


def decryptJWT(token: str) -> dict[str, str]:
    # Add decrypt JWT logic here
    app_name = ""
    if token.startswith("JWT"):
        app_name = "app1"
    elif token.startswith("Bearer"):
        app_name = "app2"
    return {"app": app_name}


def app_auth(token: str) -> str | None:
    valid_app = decryptJWT(token)
    if valid_app["app"] in APPS:
        return valid_app["app"]


def check_token(token: str | None) -> dict[str, str]:
    if not token:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            detail="Missing token",
        )
    valid_app = app_auth(token)
    if not valid_app:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Not authorized",
        )
    return {"token": token, "app": valid_app}


def handle_request(request: Request) -> dict[str, str]:
    return check_token(request.headers.get("Authorization"))


def handle_post(payload: Payload):
    return check_token(payload.token)


# First method
@app.post("/provision", tags=["Provision"])
async def provision(
    context: Annotated[dict, Depends(handle_request)] = Header(),
) -> Provision:
    return Provision(
        name=f"Name for token: {context['token']}",
        app=context["app"],
    )


# Second method
@app.post("/provision-second-way", tags=["Provision"])
async def provision_post(payload: Annotated[Payload, Body()]) -> Provision:
    context = handle_post(payload)
    return Provision(
        name=f"Name for token: {context['token']}",
        app=context["app"],
    )


# Third method
@app.post("/provision-another-way", tags=["Provision"])
async def provision_another_way(
    payload: Annotated[Payload, Body()],
) -> ProvisionAnotherWay:
    return ProvisionAnotherWay.model_validate(payload.model_dump())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # reload = True: Only in debug mode
    uvicorn.run("app:app", reload=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am marking this as helpful as I do really think you are pointing me in the right direction here (Dependency injection and so forth.) If I do understand your examples correctly, the client -> app mapping is happening in the decryptJWT() function. I do still not see how I would be able merge this into my solution as I do not have access to both provision.application and token until the path operation function executes. I´m updating the question a bit to clarify! If I am missing something please do not hesitate to call it out!

Comment: @mosbricka `ProvisionAnotherWay` is your way to go then. It's present in my example as a 3rd solution.